# Parse-server Not sending Push Notification to large Audience

Tags: mongodb, push-notification, parse-server

All push notifications with reciever with less counts sends properly but large audience push notifications get stuck at Sending and count also does not get updated.Since it is live application i am not able to send push notification with such large audience..Any idea how to debug and why is it stucked ??? All other notifications are sending and recieveing normally but large audience isnt. Its just stuck at Sending

After Debugging found out that when i call other query results are returned properly but this specific query does not returns anything...
RestQuery.prototype.runFind in RestQuery.js
does not call function with results..

And it is always stuck there.

Running the same query in mongo shell does not take more than 0.4 seconds but is always stuck in parse-server

Plus Sometimes other queries also show lost connection to mongo.
Shouldnt Parse-server handle indexing itself.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by large audience? How many installations we are talking about? also parse-server not handle indexing your MongoDB this is something that you need to do one your own and it is also mentioned in parse-server docs

Comment: Around 250k installations

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue, but as far as Parse Server 2.2.17 goes, there is a bug with the cloud code. Cloud code is having trouble working properly and they advise to roll back to 2.2.16.